# How do I use a CSI camera with ros?

Tags: opencv, ros-noetic

I am using Jetson Orin Nano connected with raspberry Pi V2.0 Camera.

I am using gstreamer pipeline to get the camera feed. It works fine with g++ build and python but as soon as I try to build it with ros catkin_make, it doesn't work. It just returs `segmentation fault ( core dumped )`

here is my implementation.

````
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/calib3d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/types_c.h>
#include <iostream>


// Include necessary ROS and other related headers
int sensor_id = 0;
int capture_width = 1280 ;
int capture_height = 720 ;
int display_width = 1280 ;
int display_height = 720 ;
int framerate = 30 ;
int flip_method = 0 ;


std::string gstreamer_pipeline (int sensor_id, int capture_width, int capture_height, int display_width, int display_height, int framerate, int flip_method) {
    return "nvarguscamerasrc sensor-id=" + std::to_string(sensor_id) +" ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=(int)" + std::to_string(capture_width) + ", height=(int)" +
           std::to_string(capture_height) + ", framerate=(fraction)" + std::to_string(framerate) +
           "/1 ! nvvidconv flip-method=" + std::to_string(flip_method) + " ! video/x-raw, width=(int)" + std::to_string(display_width) + ", height=(int)" +
           std::to_string(display_height) + ", format=(string)BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR ! appsink sync=false";
}


std::string right_camera_pipeline = gstreamer_pipeline(0,capture_width,
    capture_height,
    display_width,
    display_height,
    framerate,
    flip_method);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Initialize necessary variables and parameters
    ros::init(argc, argv, "image_subscriber_node");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    std::cout << right_camera_pipeline << std::endl;

    cv::Mat right_image;
    cv::VideoCapture right_camera(right_camera_pipeline, cv::CAP_GSTREAMER);


    if(!right_camera.isOpened() ) { //|| !left_camera.isOpened()
        std::cout<<"Failed to open camera."<<std::endl;
        return (-1);
    }
     cv::namedWindow("Right Camera", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    while(ros::ok())
    {

        if (!right_camera.read(right_image) ) { 
        std::cout<<"Capture read error"<<std::endl;
        break;     
    }

    cv::imshow("Right Camera",right_image);
    int keycode = cv::waitKey(10) & 0xff ; 
        if (keycode == 27) break ;
    }

    cv::Mat rightFrame, leftFrame, fixedLeft, fixedRight, grayLeft, grayRight, disparity, disparityImg;
    cv::Ptr<cv::StereoBM> stereoMatcher = cv::StereoBM::create();

    right_camera.release();
    // left_camera.release();
    cv::destroyAllWindows() ;
    return 0;
}
```
````